# Mono-service2 and MacOS daemon on startup

Tags: macos, unix, mono

I'm trying to make a MacOS agent to launch mono service on startup. The issue is that loaded daemon exits without any errors (no output to console.log, err.log - see agent.plist below), but mono-service2 does not create my.lock file and start a service.
**If I click on Start script manually, it runs flawlessly.** Any suggestions?

Environment:

- MacOS: Catalina 10.15.7
- Mono framework: 6.12.0.90

agent load:

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/agent.plist
```

agent.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>agent</string>

    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>me</string>

    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me/Desktop/err.log</string>

    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me/Desktop/console.log</string>

    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>

    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <true/>
    
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>

    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/bin/bash</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>bash</string>
        <string>/Applications/my.app/Contents/MacOS/Start</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Start script:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCK_FILE="my.lock"
MONO_DIR="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework"

cd `dirname "$0"` 

rm -f $LOCK_FILE
$MONO_DIR/Commands/mono-service2 -l:$LOCK_FILE Service.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that LaunchDaemon requires bash script to keep running to work properly. We can achieve this by supplying `--no-daemon` argument on *Start* script which prevents mono-service2 going background.

Complete *Start* script:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCK_FILE="my.lock"
MONO_DIR="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework"

cd `dirname "$0"` 

rm -f $LOCK_FILE
$MONO_DIR/Commands/mono-service2 -l:$LOCK_FILE Service.exe --no-daemon
```